# Removing certain edges of a graph in Networkx

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

I am generating a graph with vertices and edges. I want to remove all the edges connecting certain vertices and generate a new adjacency matrix. I present the current and expected outputs. The red cross shows the edges which should be removed.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
N=2

def pos():
    x, y = 1, N + 3 -1 
    for _ in range(2 * N * (N + 1)):
        yield (x, y)
        y -= (x + 2) // (N + 3)
        x = (x + 2) % (N + 3)

G = nx.Graph()
it_pos = pos()
for u in range(2 * N * (N + 1)):
    G.add_node(u+1, pos=next(it_pos))
    if u % (2 * N + 1) < N:
        for v in (u - 2 * N - 1, u - N - 1, u - N):
            if G.has_node(v + 1):
                G.add_edge(u + 1, v + 1)
    elif u % (2 * N + 1) == N:
        G.add_edge(u + 1, u - N + 1)
    elif u % (2 * N + 1) < 2 * N:
        for v in (u - 1, u - N - 1, u - N):
            G.add_edge(u + 1, v + 1)
    else:
        for v in (u - 1, u - N - 1):
            G.add_edge(u + 1, v + 1)

nx.draw(G, nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos'), with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')
Nodes=len(G.nodes)
A=nx.adjacency_matrix(G).todense()
A = np.squeeze(np.asarray(A))
```

The current output is

[image]

The expected output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [remove_edges_from](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.remove_edges_from.html#networkx.Graph.remove_edges_from) function.

```
# list of edges you want to remove
removeEdges = [(3,4),(1,6),(2,7),(4,5)]
G.remove_edges_from(removeEdges)
```